# MS SQL Availiability Group Failover behavior?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, high-availability

I have a client that uses MS SQL with availability groups. I develop a java based software and connect to the server in the following fasion: *jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[:portNumber]]*

Everytime the DBA does a update on the servers, we loose the connection to the server (We get a Connection Closed). According to the DBA this is normal behavior in SQL-Servers and our software should just do a retry.

Is it really normal that the sql server closes all connections in a failover situation? Shouldn't it just redirect all connections to the new instance?

Unfortunately I am no SQL-expert and the DBA is anything but helpful, he just claims that our software should simple reconnect after receiving a closed connection. Am I missing something or is this really the desired experience in sql server?

Comment: Depends on the driver, some drivers you can give it the address of the failover sever in the connection string, not sure about JDBC. I think if it's already connected then you may always get an error though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really normal that the sql server closes all connections in a failover situation? Shouldn't it just redirect all connections to the new instance?

Yes. On the assumption that the Availability Group (hereafter abbreviated "AG") is built on top of Windows Failover Clusters†, the AG listener is brought offline, transferred to new owner of the AG, and brought back online. Moreover, the databases in the AG on both the primary and all secondary replicas are transitioned from online → recovery pending → back online in their new (perhaps same as old) capacity as read/write or read-only.

Either of these phenomena alone would cause your application to lose communication with a database that it had previously established a connection with. But also, two of [the fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) are:

1. The network is reliable.
2. Topology doesn't change.

Regardless of the reason for those assumptions being violated, if your application isn't resilient to them, there's going to be a problem.

† - while it's technically possible to build an AG without Windows Clustering (i.e. a basic AG or if the AG is on Linux and is using Pacemaker as the coordinator), I think that the majority of implementations *do* use Windows Clustering.